# Консоль разработчика Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, консоль

Кто какие быстрые клавиши знает в консоли разработчика в Windows? Консоль разработчика, это та консоль, которая идет с Visual Studio.

[Горячие клавиши Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=92CED922-D505-457A-8C9C-84036160639F&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 4):

Консоль разработчика VS отличается от обычной командной строки только тем, что устанавливает некоторые переменные среды перед запуском. <sup>[источник: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx)]</sup>

Так что в ней будут работать все те же быстрые клавиши, что и в cmd.

```
    Tab      |    Автозавершение имени объекта файловой системы.
  ↓ / ↑    |    Перемещение по истории команд.
F1,F1,F1 |    Повторение символов предыдущей команды одного за другим.
      F2 Z   |    Повторение части предыдущей команды; вплоть до символа Z
      F3     |    Повторение предыдущей команды
      F4 Z   |    Начиная от текущей позиции курсора, удалить часть команды вплоть до символа Z.
      F5     |    Перемещение по истории команд (↑).
      F7     |    История последних команд.
  ALT+F7   |    Очистка истории команд
      F8     |    Перемещение по истории команд назад, но только по тем командам, которые начинаются с введённого в командную строку текста.
      F9     |    Воспроизведение команды по порядковому номеру из истории команд.
     ESC     |    Очищение строки ввода / Закрытие модального окна.
    INSERT   |    Переключение между режимами Insert/Overwrite
 Ctrl+Home  |    Стереть часть строки слева.
 Ctrl+End   |    Стереть часть строки справа.
 Ctrl+←    |    Перемещение курсора на одно слово влево (назад)
 Ctrl+→    |    Перемещение курсора на одно слово вправо (вперёд)
      ⌫     |    Стереть символ слева.
     Home    |    Перемещение к началу строки.
     End     |    Перемещение к концу строки.
  ⇧+PgUp  |    Прокрутка окна Вверх*
  ⇧+PgDn  |    Прокрутка окна Вниз*
  Ctrl+C    |    Отменить выполнение команды.
  Ctrl+Z    |    Сигнал конца файла.
```

<sub>* Может не работать в некоторых версиях Windows XP.</sub>

---

Спонсор быстрых клавиш: [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-keyboard.html).

Общепринятые обозначения

- <kbd>⌫</kbd> [backspace](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace)
- <kbd>⇧</kbd> [shift](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_(%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B0))

Answer (score 0):

```
F7 - история последних 50 команд
стрелка вверх/вниз перемещение по истории команд
```